# Vaadin slider set alphabets instead of Numbers

Tags: java, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

How could I set alphabets instead of numbers in Vaadin 8 slider.
As it has a method setValue which only accepts arguments as double number.If any other way, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "set alphabets instead of numbers"?

Comment: alphabets == String values? At which setValue(Double) method are you referring? I am not aware of such a method.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich In vaadin Slider as we slide it It shows Numbers for Indication But I want that when We slide alphabets must be Shown instead of numbers.

Comment: @rmuller by default in Vaadin slider by default we have setminValue() and setmaxValue() for the Range to be Shown Lets say 1 to 100 so our min is 1 and max is 100 by default it accepts double type arguements and setvalue sets the starting value lets say you have range 1 to 100 but you have setvalue(20) then it will show as 20 default starting value.

Comment: oops I wrote Grid sorry for that @SteffenHarbich

Comment: and @rmuller for writing grid instead of slider

Comment: Ah, Slider. And no, you can only show numbers. If you need letters, you need to implement such a component yourself.